# Disable atom opening previous files when running atom . command inside a directory

Tags: atom-editor

I frequently dislike how atom by default will open files I was previously working on when I run `atom .` inside of a project directory. How can I get atom to open with a blank editor with the file tree on the side and that's it?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable this feature by appending `restorePreviousWindowsOnStart: false` line to your Atom config file which is opened by `Edit/Config...` menu item.

See here https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/11324 for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is [you cant](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/6605)

Currently the behavior is automatic with no setting. Until that changes, you can open atom via the icon and then open the folder you want from the file menu.

Comment: This is presently not true